# R correct location of parentheses in calculating power values

Tags: r

The formula for viscosity1 is something from another script. I was concerned about what was in the exponent of the power so I tried adding some parentheses. viscosity2 and viscosity3 are two possibilities. But the results for the three viscosity formulas are all different. What am I missing?

```
Tk_test <- c(292.55, 292.75, 290.95, 290.75, 292.25, 293.85, 295.75, 295.95, 294.95)
omega <- (Tk_test / 97 - 2.9) / 0.4 * (-0.034) + 1.048
viscosity1 <- 0.0000026693 * (28.97 * Tk_test) ^ 0.5 / (3.617 ^ 2 * omega)
viscosity2 <- 0.0000026693 * (28.97 * Tk_test) ^ 0.5 / (3.617 ^ (2 * omega))
viscosity3 <- 0.0000026693 * (28.97 * Tk_test) ^ 0.5 / (3.617 ^ 2) * omega
viscosity1 == viscosity2
viscosity2 == viscosity3
```

Comment: It's a question about math than `R`. ;-)

Comment: **PEMDAS :**  parentheses, exponents, multiplication, division, addition, subtraction  _(the calculation order in math)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precedence for `^` is higher than `*` and `/`, so the parentheses are mostly changing the order of multiplication and division.

Assuming the `viscosity1` formula is the correct one, `viscosity2` is different because it does the `(2 * omega)` before raising 3.617 to a higher power. `viscosity3` is different because it multiplies by `omega` last, so it wouldn't be a part of the denominator `(3.617 ^ 2 * omega)` as it is in `viscosity1`.

Comment: PEMDAS is useful. My math classes were a long(!) time ago and maybe that wasn't presented. Hopefully, that will help me sort out parentheses location issues in the future. Of course, looking carefully would help too. Thanks!